# Convert a list of a list of strings with decimals into floats

Tags: string, python-2.7, csv, floating-point

I have a list of a list that goes like this:

```
Main_List: [ ['1.2','3.5'],[ ['5.8','8.3'] ]
```

I am trying to convert one of the sublists into floats, here is what i did:

```
Main_List[1] = [float(i) for i in Main_List[1]]
```

but i keep getting an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ."

I have tried several other methods but for some reason it keeps complaining about the dot. The lists i am trying to convert have been extracted from a csv file if that makes a difference, but i did print them and they look fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The code you wrote works fine. I think you may have problem elsewhere. [repl.it](https://repl.it/@venky18/MediumvioletredLightslategrayIndiancow)

Comment: Can you give an exact example of values you're trying to convert? Not typing, but printing out and copy-paste here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, what i had to do is create another list and set it equal to the first sublist then turn all its elements to floats.

for example

```
Sublist_1 = []
Sublist_1 = MainList[0]
Sublist_1 = map(float, Sublist_1)
```